# Change Date Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am a beginner in pandas and i have a question,I have csv file contain date 'September 19, 2019'
and I try to change it from from object to string,I confused because the comma on the date,this is my code and the warning is
`ValueError: time data 'September 9, 2019' does not match format '%B-%d-%Y'`

```
d_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%B-%d-%Y')
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv',parse_dates=['date_added'],date_parser=d_parser )
```

Comment: Can you try : `df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv',parse_dates=['date_added'])`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `pd.to_datetime()` instead of the `date_parser` argument.

```
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
df['date_added'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'],infer_datetime_format = True)
```

In your example it works fine:

```
example = 'September 9, 2019'
pd.to_datetime(example,infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Output:

```
2019-09-09 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more about telling you why your code does not work rather than telling you what would be a better approach as others already stated.

Read the error message more carefully. You tell the function that your format is going to be 'September-9-2019' but you enter in a different format 'September 9, 2019'. Try changing the parser from,

```
d_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%B-%d-%Y')
```

To,

```
d_parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%B %d, %Y')
```

My simple code to try it out:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['September 9, 2019'], columns=['date'])
parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%B %d, %Y')
parser(df.iloc[0][0])
```

The output:

> datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 9, 0, 0)